How to resolve recursive objects with the Apollo client's cache read function
I have a tree like structure in my backend described by the following GraphQL schema. Since dynamic recursion is not possible each node just contains the numerical id of it's parent but not the object itself.
type Node {
  id: Int!
  parent_id: Int
}

type Query {
  nodes(): [Node!]
}

On the Angular frontend I'm using Apollo Client to query all nodes. Now in the JS part it would be convenient to actually have recursive objects instead of just the parent_id. Something like this:
interface Node {
  id: number;
  parent: Node|null;
}

I thought I could achieve the mapping from numerical parent_id to parent object by using Apollo's type policies with a read function on a local-only field:
cache: new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Node: {
      fields: {
        parent: {
          read(_, {toReference, readField}) {
            if (!readField("parentId")) {
              return null;
            }

            return toReference({__typename: "Node", id: readField("parentId")})
          },
        },

Unfortunately the cache doesn't seem to resolve the reference to the actual object as I was hoping but just returns an object representing the reference:
query GetNodes {
  nodes {
    id
    parentId
    parent @client
  }
}

{"nodes":[{"__typename":"Node","parent":{"__ref":"Node:16"},"id":13,"parentId":16}]}

Am I overlooking something to make this work? Or can't this be achieved transparently via the Apollo client's cache?
Is there a more idiomatic way of how I could transmit the tree structure or transform the flattened one in the frontend back to a nested object representation? Or should I just keep the flattened one and lookup sub-object when needed?

Uh, if parent returns a Node, you'll have to select some subfields for a valid GraphQL query: parent @client { id }. If you had run this against a server, it would have rejected the query, but apparently Apollo cache doesn't validate your queries against the schema before running them.

Thanks @Bergi , that's indeed the reason it didn't resolve the reference. Unfortunately that brings me back to the problem of having a recursive query. Looks like I need to handle this outside of Apollo then

Hm if Apollo doesn't validate queries, you might try a recursive fragment? But yes, in general you cannot fetch a tree in tree form with GraphQL.

Nice! That seems to work. Not sure if I want to rely on it long term but for now that definitely makes my live easier. If you add this as an answer I'll mark this as the accepted solution.
